# Active Directory: Changing a name

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

I have a user with a typo'd name. For the sake of explanation, I'll say the username is lusername, first name Lindsay. Active Directory had the user initially named Lindsey Username, and I need it to be Lindsay Username. As you can tell this doesn't affect the actual login name of lusername.

If I go into Active Directory Users and Computers and search for lus, her name comes up.

I open the properties, and I can change the first name and display name fields, but I can't change the initial name at the top of the "general" tab.

Is there a way to "fix" this without resorting to recreating the user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click the user, select Rename.

First it will allow you to change the name of the user, then it will pop up a dialog box allowing you to change the Full Name, First Name, Last Name and Display Name fields.

[image]
<sub>(source: [richard-slater.co.uk](http://www.richard-slater.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/ActiveDirectoryRename.png))</sub>

Comment: Oh $DEITY I need a vacation. I can't believe that solution fell out of my brain this morning.

Comment: Took me a day to figure this out way back when I was first migrating to AD.

Comment: Hopefully others will find the question useful at some point. I so should have already remembered this...*sigh*

Comment: If you are using an Exchange server, you probably want to make sure the "Exchange Email Addresses" Tab has the correct names as well. Specifically the X.400 entry. I know the username doesn't change here, but if it does, make sure to update the alias field in the "Exchange General" Tab as well.